# Connecting a WebLogic 11g domain to a WebLogic 12c NodeManager

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g, weblogic12c

My system will be having both WebLogic 11g and WebLogic 12c domains running simultaneously on the same box.  However, there is traditionally only one NodeManger running for the machine.  If I try and connect an 11g domain to a 12c NodeManager it returns errors.  If I try and connect from a 12c domain to an 11g NodeManager I get SSL errors.

How do I configure 11g domains to connect to a 12c NodeManager during this transition period?

Comment: then make it 2 `NodeManager`s... One for each version. With different ports etc.

Comment: Ideally, it would be nice to not have to have 2 NodeManagers running.  Then alot of scripts would need to be updated to know which NodeManager they needed to connect to.

Comment: sure, but trying to connect to components of WebLogic from different versions sounds disaster-prone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting Weblogic 12c you can start a NodeManager per domain, you should keep your existing NodeManager for 11g and start a new domain specific NodeManager for 12c domain.

https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/entry/weblogic_server_12c_perdomain_node